# I can't write to bootstrap input

Tags: reactjs, input, bootstrap-4, html-datalist

I can't write to bootstrap input (choose an element in datalist yes).

Thank you very much for your help guys.

Link condesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/winter-thunder-2pne5?file=/src/App.js

```js
    import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const foodDatabase = [
    { food_id: 0, name: "rice" },
    { food_id: 1, name: "oil" },
    { food_id: 2, name: "oats" }
  ];
  const [foodNew, setFoodNew] = useState("");

  const handler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
      console.log(`${foodNew} inserted OK`);
    }
  };
  return (
    <>
      <label>
        <h2> Search your food</h2>
      </label>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={foodNew}
        list="texto_uno"
        className="form-control w-75 "
        placeholder="Search your food"
        onChange={(e) => setFoodNew(e.target.value)}
        onKeyPress={(e) => handler(e)}
      />
      <datalist id="texto_uno">
        {foodDatabase.map((item) => (
          <option key={item.food_id}>{item.name}</option>
        ))}
      </datalist>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: You `event.preventDefault();` on `keyPress`, what did you expect would happen?

Comment: Thank yout very much Yoshi, the solution has been to eliminate event.prevent.default I used it to avoid excessive renderings. I wish you an excellent day.